# Sitecore - View all items pending for approval for a particular content author

Tags: sitecore, workflow, author

While using Sitecore workflows, an item goes through the approval process and the contributors and authors can approve the item in that process. Sometimes a contributor/author has multiple items to approve. Although they get an email notification when they have an approval request in their bucket, we want to make it easier for an author to get a snapshot view of all the approval requests that s/he has in her/his task list. In this way s/he will be able to approve all her/his tasks in one go.

We understand that Sitecore provides the Workbox where users can view a snapshot of the items and their workflow states. But since these can only be filtered by the workflow and not by the user in question, it can get a little overwhelming for the content authors. Please let us know if Sitecore provides any such mechanism for an author to view a list of his/her pending tasks ONLY and take actions on them. If Sitecore does not provide such a functionality OOB, please let us know how to implement this.

Comment: And how do you know that it's their task? If they see it in the workbox it means they can approve it...

Comment: @Marek Can the tasks be filtered according to the user?

Comment: There is nothing like tasks assigned to users in Sitecore OOTB. If you created some custom field with "Task Owner", you need to write custom code to handle that.

Comment: I am also a little confused by the question. Security dictates who can access a particular stage in a workbox. If the item is in the workbox, then it is for them.

Can you clarify how you are distinguishing which tasks are for a particular user? Do they have items in their state that they are allowed to approve via permissions but are not supposed to? (Sounds like a permission problem)

Answer (score 0):

You could download and install the Advanced Workbox that can filter by user like (My Items).

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/A/Advanced_Workbox.aspx?sc_lang=en